# MySQL-error 150 solution

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

I have the following MySQL scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  access INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_created DATETIME,
    roles VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    active INT DEFAULT '1',
    FOREIGN KEY(roles) REFERENCES user_roles(id)
)
```

It keeps giving me error 150. Maybe the database isn't well planned? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data types of your `users.roles` and `user_roles.id` columns must be the same for the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to work correctly.  Instead try making `users.roles` an `INT`:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_created DATETIME,
    -- Change this...
    roles INT NOT NULL,
    active INT DEFAULT '1',
    FOREIGN KEY(roles) REFERENCES user_roles(id)
)
```

**UPDATE** According to comments, `users.roles` should be text like "admin, moderator, etc." For correct data normalization, `user_roles.id` should be keyed against and to get the text name of the role, `JOIN` them in queries.

Comment: Ok. This scripts were given in SQL form by a friend of mine and by roles he means something like admin,moderator,user and etc...I know that if I change the types it will work. This field should contain text information

Comment: @George if that's the case, `id` is not the right column to key against.  It may be `user_roles.text`, but then that column should probably be  a `VARCHAR()` rather than `TEXT`

Comment: @George For correct normalization, `id` should be used though, and use a `JOIN` in queries to retrieve the text name of the role.

Comment: This wasn't entirely written by myself. Yes it should be called access-levels

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your statements with a semicolon and use INTS instead of strings:

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  access INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_created DATETIME,
    roles VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    active INT DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY(roles) REFERENCES user_roles(id)
);
```

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table 'main.users' (errno: 150)

Comment: Weird, I just ran the SQL and it worked fine for me. What version of MySQL are you running?